# Java - Basic Multithreading

Tags: java

I would like to ask  basic question about Java threads. Let's consider a producer - consumer scenario. Say there is one producer, and n consumer. Consumer arrive at random time, and once they are served they go away, meaning each consumer runs on its own thread. Should I still use run forever condition for consumer ?

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
        }
    }
}
```

Won't this keep thread running forever ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. This thread will indeed run forever. Whether or not to use a run-forever condition is completely down to you.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't extend Thread, instead I would implement Runnable.

If you want the thread to run forever, I would have it loop forever.

A common alternative is to use

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

or

```
while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
```

Comment: Does this give guarantee that others thread (consumer who are not served) won't die early ?

Comment: Having one thread stop another isn't something which just happens.  Actually its something which isn't that simple to do.  Can you explain why you would be concerned that other threads might die?

Comment: Glad you asked. I am new to Java and OOP for that matter. Say there are 5 consumer at any given time, and they are waiting to be served by producer. So, obviously there will be 5 consumer threads. Since Thread.interrupted() is a static method, if one thread interrupts wouldn't it cause all other threads to die as well ?

Comment: Each thread has its own interrupted flag. There is no simple way to interrupt every thread.

Answer (score 1):

It will,  so you might want to do something like

```
while(beingServed)
{
    //check if the customer is done being served (set beingServed to false)
}
```

This way you'll escaped the loop when it's meant to die.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `boolean` that represents the presence of the Consumer?

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean present;

    public Consumer() {
        present = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (present) {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }

    public void consumerLeft() {
        present = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: present should be volatile. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I knew I forgot something :P

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create for each consumer and after the consumer will finish it's job than the consumer will finish the run function and will die, so no need for infinite loop. however, creating thread for each consumer is not good idea since creation of thread is quite expensive in performance point of view. threads are very expensive resources. In addition, i agree with the answers above that it is better to implement runnable and not to extends thread. extend thread only when you wish to customize your thread.
I strongly suggest you will use thread pool and the consumer will be the runnable object that ran by the thread in the thread pool.
the code should look like this:

```
public class ConsumerMgr{

 int poolSize = 2;

int maxPoolSize = 2;

long keepAliveTime = 10;

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = null;

final ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(
        5);

public ConsumerMgr()
{
    threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize,
            keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

}

public void runTask(Runnable task)
{
    // System.out.println("Task count.."+threadPool.getTaskCount() );
    // System.out.println("Queue Size before assigning the
    // task.."+queue.size() );
    threadPool.execute(task);
    // System.out.println("Queue Size after assigning the
    // task.."+queue.size() );
    // System.out.println("Pool Size after assigning the
    // task.."+threadPool.getActiveCount() );
    // System.out.println("Task count.."+threadPool.getTaskCount() );
    System.out.println("Task count.." + queue.size());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to *extend* Thread (unless you are coding a new kind of thread - ie never).

The best approach is to pass a [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to the Thread's constructor, like this:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
```

In general, `while(true)` is OK, but you have to handle being interrupted, either by normal `wake` or by spurious wakeup. There are many examples out there on the web.

I recommend reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/).

Comment: What is wake? And how do you trigger a spurious wakeup? Isn't a spurious wakeup, by definition, a wakeup that hasn't been caused by code?

Answer (score 0):

for producer-consumer pattern you better use wait() and notify(). See this  [tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306). This is far more efficient than using while(true) loop.

Comment: It would be even better and simpler to use a BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your thread to processes messages until you kill them (or they are killed in some way) inside `while (true)` there would be some synchronized call to your producer thread (or SynchronizedQueue, or queuing system) which would block until a message becomes available. Once a message is consumed, the loop restarts and waits again.

If you want to manually instantiate a bunch of thread which pull a message from a producer just once then die, don't use `while (true)`.